# getting plots from event logs using pm4py

Tags: python

I have an event log dataset which has the following columns:

```
   case:concept:name    concept:name    time:timestamp
```

My goal is to obtain a distribution of events according to the date it occurred.

I have used the naming convention for the columns as shown above because I have been performing process mining tasks using the package called PM4Py. To obtain a distribution as required, I used the csv reading function in PM4Py and performed some tasks using the pandas package.

Here is what I tried after reading the csv file into a dataframe object named 'df' :

```
date = []
for i,row in df.iterrows():
  date.append(row['time:timestamp'].date())
df['Date'] = date #Creating a new column with only the date values

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df['Date'].value_counts().index, df['Date'].value_counts()) 
plt.show()
```

Here the timestamp column is a pandas datetime object. The output seemed to somewhat produce what is required. But, I wish to know if there is a more elegant way to do this using PM4Py or any similar package?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pm4py.visualization.graphs` module, which seems to implement the functionality you are looking for (http://pm4py.pads.rwth-aachen.de/documentation/obtaining-graphs-from-trace-log/).

It can produce plots for distribution with respect to case duration, time or any numerical attribute.

Comment: The link to the docs did not work for me.